# Smartphone recommendation

Tags: smartphones

I'm looking for a new smartphone to replace my aging OnePlus 6.
I tried replacing it so far with...

- A OnePlus 7T Pro - Screen was waaay too curved. Front camera too slow for FaceID, In-Screen fingerprint sensor too slow for fingerprint ID.
- A OnePlus 7T - almost perfect, but the screen was very un-uniform at low brightness
- A Galaxy S10, which killed its glass front after a mild drop thanks to the curved screen and horribly designed silicon case

My requirements are:

- No curved screen
- 90+ Hz display
- Contemporary processor, SnapDragon 855 or better / comparable
- Camera doesn't matter
- Fingerprint sensor, but not In-Display
- OR In-Display fingerprint sensor, but a conventional front-facing camera (not mechanized)
- Android, with bonus points for not losing warranty when rooted.

I've found a few promising devices so far - I like the Nubia Red Magic 3S, but it seems to be hard to source in Germany.
Price doesn't really matter, but should be adequate for the performance.

Comment: I think the Red Magic 3 is the only choice with all those specs up to now. It beats the S10 performance wise by a lot too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Realme X2 Pro**

The Realme X2 Pro is the cheapest phone with 90Hz display in India right now. apart from the headlining refresh rate feature, it also packs Snapdragon 855 Plus chipset, a 6.5-inch Fluid AMOLED Full-HD+ screen, and among the highest fast-charging tech in the industry. The Realme X2 Pro is a first-ever flagship offering from the brand, designed to take on the likes of the Redmi K20 Pro and OnePlus 7T.

**2.Nubia Red Magic 3s**

Next in the list of phones with 90Hz screen is nubia’s gaming-focused Red Magic 3s  smartphone. The handset is an iterative upgrade from the Red Magic 3 smartphone, which was introduced earlier this year. The Red Magic 3s sports a 6.65-inch Super AMOLED display that bears 90Hz refresh rate, DC dimming, HDR support, and full-HD+ (1,080p) resolution.

**3.ASUS ROG Phone 2**

This gaming-focused phone has 120Hz refresh rate display. The ASUS ROG Phone 2 features a 6.59-inch AMOLED display with 120Hz refresh rate and 240Hz touch sampling. The screen has fair amounts of bezels that houses front-firing speakers for an immersive gaming experience. To take care of that high refresh rate, the ROG Phone 2 houses an astounding 6,000mAh battery with 30W fast charging support.

**4.Google Pixel 4 series**

Although the Pixel 4 series is not coming to India, it’s one of the smartphones out there to sport 90Hz screens. Both the Pixel 4 and Pixel 4 XL sports display with a high refresh rate. The handsets are the latest flagships from Google that comes running Android 10 out of the box and features dual rear cameras with a dedicated telephoto lens.

**5.OPPO Reno Ace**

The OPPO Reno Ace is the first smartphone from the brand with 90Hz screen. OPPO has introduced the handset only in China so far. It’s a mid-range offering that sports a 6.5-inch 1080p OLED display that bears refresh rate of up to 90Hz refresh rate and 135Hz sampling rate for a smooth experience. The screen also features a waterdrop notch that accommodates selfie camera and optical fingerprint scanner for biometrics.

**6.Samsung Galaxy S10 Lite**

Key Specs

Android v10 (Q)

Performance(Excellent)
Octa core (2.84 GHz, Single Core + 2.42 GHz, Tri core + 1.8 GHz, Quad core)
Snapdragon 855
8 GB RAM

Display(Very Good)
6.7 inches (17.02 cm)
1080x2400 px, 393 PPI
Super AMOLED Plus

Camera(Excellent)
48 MP + 12 MP + 5 MP Triple Primary Cameras
LED Flash
32 MP Front Camera, No Front Flash
Battery(Very Good)

4500 mAh
Fast Charging
USB Type-C port

**7.Redmi K20 Pro**

Key Specs
 Android v9.0 (Pie)

Performance(Excellent)

Octa core (2.84 GHz, Single Core + 2.42 GHz, Tri core + 1.8 GHz, Quad core)
Snapdragon 855
8 GB RAM

Display(Very Good)
6.39 inches (16.23 cm)
1080x2340 px, 403 PPI
AMOLED

Camera(Very Good)
48 MP + 13 MP + 8 MP Triple Primary Cameras
Dual LED Flash
20 MP Front Camera

Battery(Very Good)
4000 mAh
Quick Charging 4.0
USB Type-C port

**8.Asus 6Z**

Key Specs
 Android v9.0 (Pie)

Performance(Excellent)
Octa core (2.84 GHz, Single Core + 2.42 GHz, Tri core + 1.8 GHz, Quad core)
Snapdragon 855
6 GB RAM

Display(Good)
6.4 inches (16.26 cm)
1080x2340 px, 403 PPI
IPS LCD

Camera(Very Good)
48 MP + 13 MP Dual Primary Cameras
Dual LED Flash
48 MP + 13 MP Dual Front Cameras, Dual LED
Battery(Excellent)

5000 mAh
Quick Charging 4.0
USB Type-C port

**9.Black Shark 2**

Key Specs
 Android v9.0 (Pie)

Performance(Excellent)
Octa core (2.84 GHz, Single Core + 2.42 GHz, Tri core + 1.8 GHz, Quad core)
Snapdragon 855
12 GB RAM

Display(Very Good)
6.39 inches (16.23 cm)
1080x2340 px, 403 PPI
AMOLED

Camera(Very Good)
48 MP + 12 MP Dual Primary Cameras
LED Flash
20 MP Front Camera

Battery(Very Good)
4000 mAh
Quick Charging 4.0
USB Type-C port

**Hopefully These Phones May Fullfill Your Requirements.**

Comment: I agree those would fit requirements, but IF you’re open to switching to an Apple iPhone, I would get an iPhone Xr or iPhone Xs (non-max) or iPhone 11 (Non-max or pro)

Comment: Thank you for your effort and this very comprehensive list!
I was not aware of the Realme X2 Pro, and it's much easier to source here - though rooting seems to void their warranty. Guess it's a compromise either way.

Comment: So I've just bought a Redmi X2 Pro locally - same horrible screen quality at low brightness as on the OnePlus 7T.

Comment: Actually redme x2 pro is known for fast Charging and budget performance compared to one plus maybe screen brightness solved in next update if its software issue else have to use in same way.